# Using riverpod to maintain a global Map<String, int> in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have implemented a provider using the new syntax based on the example of counter in the riverpod documentation.

Riverpod Example:

```
@riverpod
class CounterNotifier extends $CounterNotifier {
@override
int build() = 0;
void increment() = state++;
void decrement() = state++;
}
```

My provider:

```
@riverpod
class ViewsCounterNotifier extends _$ViewsCounterNotifier {
@override
Map<String, int> build() {
return {};
} 
void add(String id) {
if (state.containsKey(id)) {
state[id] = state[id]! + 1;
} else {
state[id] = 1;
print(state);
}
}
}
```

Im able to read and update the map first time using
ref.read(viewsCounterNotifierProvider.notifier).add(widget.product.id!);

but any subseequent read leads to re-initialization of provider because of

```
@override
Map<String, int> build() {
return {};
}
```

and previous data is lost. How to maintain the data.

Comment: Providers are autodispose per default with riverpod code generation. Make it keepalive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generated providers have an auto-disposing behavior by default. If there are no listeners to the provider, the state will reset. To disable auto dispose, specify `keepAlive: true` in the annotation. Change `@riverpod` to:

```dart
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
```

Another problem in your code is the use of mutable state in the provider. In short, you should not mutate the state object and expect the provider to notice the state update. A minimal change to make the `add` method works is to have a copied state before reassigning it to the notifier state:

```dart
@riverpod
class ViewsCounterNotifier extends _$ViewsCounterNotifier {
  @override
  Map<String, int> build() {
    return {};
  }

  void add(String id) {
    final copiedState = {...state}; // Copy the state to a local variable

    // Make mutations to the local map object
    if (copiedState.containsKey(id)) {
      copiedState[id] = copiedState[id]! + 1;
    } else {
      copiedState[id] = 1;
    }

    // Reassign the state with the modified local map object
    state = copiedState;
  }
}
```

A better approach might be to use [control-flow operators](https://dart.dev/language/collections#control-flow-operators).

Comment: Thank you, keepAlive worked, the reason Im mutating the state object directly is because I dont need to update any widgets/.watch using this map. In this case I dont need to implement the workaround, right?

Comment: Well, yes actually. But it's prone to error, in case someone (maybe yourself) in the future forget about this and use ref.watch somewhere, so generally good practice to use immutable state (or pretend the immutability).

Comment: Okay, suggestion to use control-flow operators was helpful as well. Thank you.

Comment: simplified: `void add(String id) => state = {...state}..update(id, (v) => v + 1, ifAbsent: () => 1);`